# My MySQL function doesn't insert a value

Tags: mysql, performance

This is my code:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM User WHERE Username = @Username) THEN
    RETURN -1;
ELSEIF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM User WHERE Email = @Email) 
THEN
    RETURN -2;
ELSE
    INSERT INTO User(Username, Password, Email) 
    VALUES ('Nicki',@Password,@Email);
    RETURN LAST_INSERT_ID();
END IF
```

And an image

[image: Image from Function]

But the function doesn't insert a value — can you explain why not?

Comment: Do you already have a user called Nicki? You are hardcoding "Nicki" into the insert, rather than using @Username as I'd expect here. If you already have a username Nicki, and the field is Unique/Primary Key etc, it will fail. If this isn't the case, run the two `SELECT` statements (`SELECT * FROM User WHERE Username = @Username` and the same for the Email one) yourself, specifying the Username and Email. Check whether they return values

Comment: What was your returned value?

Comment: Hey okay thanks, but i dont have any Values in my Tabel. And her is my Structure: https://pastebin.com/kZ0zaxD4

Comment: I dont have an returned value... its null.. :(

Comment: Your parameters don't have@ in them so I would change the code to remove the @ ,change the parameter names to be pre-ceeded by in and change the code to match. As a matter of interest why would you want to do this using a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Username` is a [9.4 User-Defined Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) and `Username` is a table column.

Also, check: [C.1 Restrictions on Stored Programs::Name Conflicts within Stored Routines](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html).

Try:

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.18    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `InsertUser`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `User`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `User`(
    ->   `Id` BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   `Username` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ->   `Password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ->   `Email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> CREATE FUNCTION `InsertUser`(`_Username` VARCHAR(255),
    ->                              `_Email` VARCHAR(255),
    ->                              `_Password` VARCHAR(255)
    -> )
    -> RETURNS INT
    -> LANGUAGE SQL
    -> DETERMINISTIC
    -> MODIFIES SQL DATA
    -> BEGIN
    ->   IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `User` WHERE `Username` = `_Username`) THEN
    ->     RETURN -1;
    ->   ELSEIF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `User` WHERE `Email` = `_Email`) THEN
    ->     RETURN -2;
    ->   ELSE
    ->     INSERT INTO `User` (`Username`, `Password`, `Email`)
    ->     VALUES ('Nicki', `_Password`, `_Email`);
    ->     RETURN LAST_INSERT_ID();
    ->   END IF;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `Id`,
    ->   `Username`,
    ->   `Password`,
    ->   `Email`
    -> FROM
    ->   `User`;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `InsertUser`(NULL, 'pass', 'email@domain.ext');
+------------------------------------------------+
| `InsertUser`(NULL, 'pass', 'email@domain.ext') |
+------------------------------------------------+
|                                              1 |
+------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `Id`,
    ->   `Username`,
    ->   `Password`,
    ->   `Email`
    -> FROM
    ->   `User`;
+----+----------+------------------+-------+
| Id | Username | Password         | Email |
+----+----------+------------------+-------+
|  1 | Nicki    | email@domain.ext | pass  |
+----+----------+------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `InsertUser`(NULL, 'pass', 'email@domain.ext');
+------------------------------------------------+
| `InsertUser`(NULL, 'pass', 'email@domain.ext') |
+------------------------------------------------+
|                                             -2 |
+------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Example [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sVUrRaLzJnAUH3c3pX657t/1).